# can we copy the node before dropping the parent node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to restrict some node to add in parent node. I want to check one condition before dropping a node, if node has (to whom dropped) child it will not drop else if it has no child it will drop. I think I need to use copy concept .

**In detail:** Please check only two node "c-a","c-b".if they drop on "a" they become child of "a".but if they drop on "b" they can't drop and come back to it original position.but if they drop on "b-a" they can become child of"b-a".

Is this possible? I did check API available [here](http://www.jstree.com/api/) but no one work like that.

**Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/122/):**

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
       check_callback: function (op, node, node_parent) {
          console.log(op);
           console.log(node)
           console.log(node_parent.id)
          return op == 'move_node' ? node_parent.id.indexOf('not') === -1 : true;
       }
    },
    dnd: {
       is_draggable: function (x) {
          return x[0].id.indexOf('not') === -1;
       }
    },
    "plugins": ["dnd"]
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go (again)

```
//we'll call the node having `not` in its id, a "n_node"
$('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
       check_callback: function (op, node, node_parent) {
          var ret = true;
          if (op == 'move_node' && node.id.indexOf('not') !== -1) {
             //n_node can only be dropped in an empty non-n_node
             ret = node_parent.id.indexOf('not') === -1 && !node_parent.children.length;
          }
          return ret;
       }
    },
    dnd: {
       check_while_dragging: false
    },
    "plugins": ["dnd"]
 });
```

**Update**

for `jsfiddle.net/fuu94/127 in this fiddle user can add node "a" , "b","b-a","b-b","b-b-a","b-b-b" inside "c-a","c-b".can we restrict them`,

```
//function to check n_node in one place
function isNNode(node) {return node.id.indexOf('not') !== -1;}
```

and replace your condition

```
if (op == 'move_node' && node.id.indexOf('not') !== -1) {
    //n_node can only be dropped in an empty non-n_node
    ret = node_parent.id.indexOf('not') === -1 && !node_parent.children.length;
}
```

with following

```
if (op == 'move_node') {
    ret = isNNode(node) ? !isNNode(node_parent) && !node_parent.children.length : !isNNode(node_parent);
}
```

I hope your all issues are resolved now.

Comment: Provide a fiddle for the same to illustrate better.

Comment: @ejay can you please provide fiddle

Comment: @ejay Thanks for Help I need one more help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/127/ in this fiddle user can add node "a" , "b","b-a","b-b","b-b-a","b-b-b" inside "c-a","c-b".can we restrict them.

Comment: @ejay can you look my last question I will not ask more after that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678032/how-to-drag-node-inside-the-parent-node-which-have-id-not

Comment: @ejay you are the only one who can solve my last problem Thanks